# Chrome Extension Can't call any methods in background page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I have been trying for a while but I'm unable to call any methods on my background page js file.

My manifest looks like this:

```
{
  "name" : "First chrome extension",
  "version" : "0.0.1",
  "manifest_version" : 2,
  "browser_action" : {
    "default_title" : "Practice",
    "default_icon" : {
      "16" : "assets/images/icon16.png",
      "24" : "assets/images/icon24.png",
      "32" : "assets/images/icon32.png"
    },
   "default_popup" : "popup.html"
  },
  "background" : {
    "scripts" : ["background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts" : [{
    "matches" : ["*://*/*"], 
    "js" : [
      "assets/js/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js",
      "assets/js/content.js"
     ]
  }],
  "permissions" : [
    "activeTab",
    "storage"
  ]
}
```

background.js:

```
function test()
{
  return 'called';
}
```

assets/js/popup.js:

```
console.log(chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().test());
```

Most of the examples I saw used the chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage method to retrieve the background but whenever I try this method it tells me the method or any other variable I set in background.js is undefined and they're not present on the returned window object.

I also tried using the messaging API like so:
background.js

```
"use strict";

const test = function() {
    console.log(1);
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse){
    console.log(request);  
    if(request.msg.toLowerCase()  === "bg-test") test();
  }
);
```

assets/js/popup.js:

```
$(function() {
  const btn = '#en-dis-btn';
  $(btn).click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'msg' : 'bg-test'}, function(response) {
       console.log(response);
    });
  });
});
```

but the listener in background.js is never called. What could I be doing wrong? The background page is not null so it is loading something.

Comment: 1) `"scripts" : ["background.js"]` should use `assets/js/background.js` - is it a typo? 2) you're not sending any response via sendResponse in the listener. 3) start using devtools debugger: set breakpoints in the background page and the popup, run the code and see what happens. 4) make sure to reload the extension on chrome://extensions page 5) and just in case, [Google Chrome / Firefox do not see extension output in console](//stackoverflow.com/a/38920982)

Comment: @wOxxOm it was a typo but it was right in the code, I just wrote it wrong here.

2) I'm aware, I just need the console logs to run for now but it's not even getting to that point.

3) I'll set breakpoints in the background and ge tback to you

4) Always reload and use the extension console so i should see logs.

Comment: I managed removed the extensions and added it again and the messaging worked but I still don't understand why I can't get the method using getBackgroundPage(), that's my main issue

Comment: That could happen if you use `const test = function() { }` because const/let variables can't be accessed from another page.

Comment: @wOxxOm Dang, I forgot about let and const scoping. I haven't used Javascript in months. Would you mind posting an answer so I can give you the answer, you deserve the rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ECMA specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-let-and-const-declarations):

> `let` and `const` declarations define variables that are scoped to the running execution context’s LexicalEnvironment.

When you declare a let/const variable globally in one page (the background page), the variable's LexicalEnvironment is scoped that page's global `this` (which equals the page's `window`) and another page (the popup) is clearly outside of that scope.

Use `var foo = bar` or `function foo() {}` declaration, which exposes it as a *property* of the `window` object so it's visible in another same-origin `chrome-extension://*extensionID*` page such as the popup page.